# How do I detect the frequency of an LFO signal using numpy.fft.fft?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, signal-processing, fft

Suppose I have an LFO signal of frequency, say, 7 Hz. Also, the input signal contains other audio data (other waves). I can get only 100 last samples, each sample is a 16-bit signed value between the range -32768 to 32767. (Sampling occurs 11025 times a second.) (The device is Critter & Guitari ETC.)

My question is: How using `numpy` could I extract from the last 100 samples the magical number of 7 (the frequency of the LFO signal)?

Comment: FFT will output the entire frequency spectrum of the signal. All the contributing frequencies will be present with different magnitudes depending on the contribution of each to the signal. Calculating it with numpy is quite easy, but I don't think anyone will be able to help you without seeing what you have tried or at least a sample of the signal.

Comment: at 11 khz sampling rate, one cycle of 7 hz is 1575 samples. if you only have 100 samples to look at, this task will be impossible. you will need to figure out a way to get more history.

Comment: Can you store something in-between frames? Another thing - what you want to achieve, you need to measure signal frequency OR magnitude for given frequency OR detect is signal is present OR something else?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz OK, thanks! That pretty much answers my question. I will go for searching another solution.